# Space of Contact Forms in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contractible. Some fact about Volume Forms

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

To show that a space of contact forms in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contractible, it's enough to show that
$$\lambda_t=(1-t)\lambda_1+t\lambda_2$$
is a contact form for all $t\in[0,1]$ if $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$ are contact forms.

By the definition, $\lambda$ is a contact form if $\lambda\wedge d\lambda$ is a volume form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ i.e. $\lambda\wedge d\lambda\neq 0$. Then observe that
$$\lambda_t\wedge d\lambda_t=(1-t)^2\lambda_1\wedge d\lambda_1+t^2\lambda_2\wedge d\lambda_2+$$
$$+t(1-t)\lambda_1\wedge d\lambda_2+t(1-t)\lambda_2\wedge d\lambda_1.$$
Assume that $\lambda_t\wedge d\lambda_t=0$ i.e. there exists a non-zero $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for all $v,w\in \mathbb{R}^3$,
$$(\lambda_t\wedge d\lambda_t)(x,v,w)=0.$$
The main thing that I want to argue that we can choose $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $d\lambda_1(v,w)=0$, $d\lambda_2(v,w)\neq0$, and $v\in \ker(\lambda_1)$. Then we have that
$$0=(\lambda_t\wedge d\lambda_t)(x,v,w)=(t^2\lambda_2\wedge d\lambda_2+t(1-t)\lambda_1\wedge d\lambda_2)(x,v,w)=(t^2\lambda_2\wedge d\lambda_2)(x,v,w)\neq 0$$
which gives us a contradiction. However, how can I gurantee that $x\not\in\ker(\lambda_2)$? So, if I can find such $v,w$ and $x\not\in\ker(\lambda_2)$, then $\lambda_t\wedge d\lambda_t$ is indeed a contact form on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I hope this proof more or less correct. If I want to generalize it to $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$, do I work in the same way? Or, is there more consice intuitive proof of this fact?

Comment: What topology are you placing on the space of contact forms? Also, here you're trying to prove the stronger condition that the space of contact forms is *convex*. This is false, since for any contact form $\lambda$, $-\lambda$ is also a contact form, but $0$ is not.

Comment: @Kajelad, I was trying to show contractability from convexity. Thank you for your counterexample. About topology, as I understand, the space of contact forms $\Lambda$ is the subspace of $T^*\mathbb{R}^3$. Can we just use the induced topology from $T^*\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: It is a *subset* of the space of *sections* $\Gamma(T^*\mathbb{R}^3)$. This is an infinite-dimensional vector space, so there are various choices of topology, depending on what you're interested in doing with it.